# Why does (1 == 2 != 3) evaluate to False in Python?

Tags: python, operator-precedence

Why does `(1 == 2 != 3)` evaluate to `False` in Python, while both `((1 == 2) != 3)` and `(1 == (2 != 3))` evaluate to `True`?

What operator precedence is used here?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is due to the operators' *[chaining phenomenon](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons)*. The Python documentation explains it as:

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., **x < y <= z** is equivalent
> to **x < y and y <= z**, except that y is evaluated only once (but in both
> cases z is not evaluated at all when x < y is found to be false).

And if you look at [the precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) of the `==` and `!=` operators, you will notice that they have the **same precedence** and hence applicable to the **chaining phenomenon**.

So basically what happens:

```
>>>  1==2
=> False
>>> 2!=3
=> True

>>> (1==2) and (2!=3)
  # False and True
=> False
```

Comment: The fact that `==` and `!=` are both comparison operators is more important than the fact that they have the same precedence. `>>` and `<<` also have the same precedence, but `x << y >> z` isn't the same as `x << y and y >> z`.

Answer (score 4):

A chained expression, like `A op B op C` where `op` are comparison operators, is in contrast to C evaluated as (*[Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/2.3/ref/comparisons.html)* in the Python Reference Manual):

```
A op B and B op C
```

Thus, your example is evaluated as

```
1 == 2 and 2 != 3
```

which results to `False`.