# How is 1 == 2 == 2 evaluated?

Tags: python

Running this in the REPL gives me

```py
>>> 1 == 2 == 2
False
```

Which surprised me, in C this would evaluate to 1. I expected the right-hand side to evaluate to `True` and `1 == True` is `True` in Python. For example, this evaluates as I would expect:

```py
>>> 1 == (2 == 2)
True
```

How is Python parsing and evaluating the first expression? This, evaluates the same way but this is what I would expect because `==` is right-associative and would evaluate to 0 in C

```
>>> 2 == 2 == 1
False
```

Comment: May be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47900237/why-does-1-2-3-evaluate-to-false-in-python

Comment: `==` is a comparison operator, so this is being chained, i.e. `(1 == 2) and (2 == 2)`. This is the same as `1 < 2 < 2`

Comment: The comparisons are evaluated left to right. See [Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) in the documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is due to the operators [chaining phenomenon](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons)

An example :

```
>>>  1==2
=> False
>>> 2!=3
=> True

>>> (1==2) and (2!=3)
  # False and True
=> False
```

Comment: Ahh thank you! This makes sense to me

Comment: A pleasure mate, I found this in the doc when I was coding last time, so it was in my favorite.